# JGit : I want to get all files and folders in a particular branch

Tags: java, spring, git, git-branch, jgit

I have seen a lot of tutorials but I haven't found any code for getting all the files and folders in a particular branch.

I have tried this piece of code

```
File src = new File("C:\\Users\\Winfo\\Documents\\GitHub\\WDAS");
    org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Repository repo = new FileRepositoryBuilder().readEnvironment().findGitDir(src).build();
    Git git = new Git(repo);
    git.checkout()
    .setName("new-branch")
    .setStartPoint("commit id") // commit id here
    .call();
```

This is creating a separate Branch based on the commit id, but I need to clone the list of files and folders in a local repository based on the branch.

I am new to JGit, could someone help with my requirement. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may do something like this below to pull from a particular branch

```
Git.cloneRepository()
  .setURI("https://github.com/eclipse/jgit.git") // your git url
  .setDirectory(new File("/path/to/repo")) 
  .setBranchesToClone(Arrays.asList("refs/heads/specific-branch"))// give ur branch name
  .setBranch("refs/heads/specific-branch")
  .call();
```

For more information: [read here](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JGit/article.html)